# How to set up sqlmembership provider for existing database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Can any one tell me please how to set up sqlmembership provider for my existing database. Now i can create new database using aspnet_regsql.exe but using this I don't know how to set up for my existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run:

> aspnet_regsql.exe

You will be prompted to select your database. After the wizard is completed it will have generated the aspnet_ membership tables in your database.

[image]

Comment: I was confused since Database is not listed for me. Once I entered my database name, its working.

Comment: No problem, glad it's sorted for you.